# What regulations in the US exist for jetpacks?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa

In 2010 Fox News posted [an article](http://www.foxnews.com/scitech/2010/03/13/future-jetpacks-sale-late-year/) in which they quoted a representative of the FAA saying that the FAA might not regulate jetpacks (the representative did say that they could fall under Part 103). Do any regulations exist in the US for jetpacks?

Comment: If they don't regulate them, then I guess the answer is no?

Comment: The article, and I think the FAA rep, actually suggests that they very well might fall under Part 103 (ultralights).

Comment: Right, the answer would be "No, none exist." It may be that no one can find any sort of reference to regulation of jetpacks other than that previous statement by the FAA. I'm fine with that answer; I'm just trying to see if jetpacks fit into some regulation somewhere.

Comment: @egid Yes, but it does mention that there was some hesitation over whether to even put jetpacks under Part 103.

Comment: Another thing I'm curious about is this: If the FAA definitively said they do not regulate jetpacks, would a jetpack user (in theory) be allowed to fly in any airspace (except maybe TFR)?

Comment: @called2voyage I bet you'd still be shot down.

Comment: @PatoSáinz Obviously, thus the "in theory" part.

Comment: Someone apparently was flying a jetpack in the Class B airspace around LAX last weekend and the [FBI has gotten involved](https://www.ign.com/articles/fbi-investigating-pilots-reports-of-mysterious-jet-pack-man). If someone actually got up to 3000 feet then today's jetpacks are significantly more capable then those of 10 years ago. Apparently this is being considered a flight...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Might need a new answer then!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by a "jetpack". If you mean the classic James Bond-style rocket pack, then according to an FAA spokesman [quoted](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB123655460908765815) in the Wall Street Journal they just don't fly long enough for the FAA to be interested:

> Once aloft, a jetpack pilot is preoccupied with getting down quickly:
>   A typical pack holds about 10 gallons of fuel, only enough to fly for
>   about half a minute. The Federal Aviation Administration doesn't
>   regulate jetpacks. "Thirty seconds is not sufficient to be considered
>   a flight," says FAA spokesman Les Dorr. He adds that it's up to the
>   individual to assess the risks.

On the other hand if you're referring to the [Martin Jetpack](http://www.martinjetpack.com/), which uses fans instead of rockets, then several sources (e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Jetpack)) say that it's considered an ultralight by the FAA, in which case all the usual ultralight regulations would apply. But I couldn't find any direct confirmation of that on Martin's site.

Comment: Sounds about like what I would expect, thanks.

Comment: `Thirty seconds is not sufficient to be considered a flight` . . . [Sorry Orville!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_Flyer#Flight_trials_at_Kitty_Hawk) :-)