# Is this legal for transportation in the US? (video in description)

Tags: faa-regulations

I wanted to make something like this, but I don't know if this is legal for transportation.

Comment: What kind of transportation? Anywhere through the air?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/764/62)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class [G airspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airspace_class) provided [proper separation from people and buildings](http://rgl.faa.gov/regulatory_and_guidance_library/rgfar.nsf/b4a0cab3e513bb58852566c70067018f/91693c93525de33e862576c100763e31!OpenDocument) you should be good to go. The airspace you are in can be determined by geographic location and altitude using the [FAA's charts you can find here.](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/productcatalog/vfrcharts/Sectional/)

> legal for transportation.

This is a somewhat broad term. The FAA may require you to get it set up as an [experimental aircraft](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/airworthiness_certification/sp_awcert/experiment/) but thats up to them. If you plan to do more than hop around empty farms and over a pond you may want to [contact your local FSDO](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/field_offices/fsdo/) for a ruling on what you can do. You can also [reach out directly to the FAA for a ruling on a specific question.](https://www.faa.gov/contact/)

The FAA as per

> [**§ 1.1 General definitions.**](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/1.1)
>
> ....
>
> **Aircraft** means a device that is used or intended to be used for flight in the air.

does define what you show as an aircraft and would most likely see it as falling under their purview.

Note that since he is over open water he has a life jacket on board ([although he is within the required 50 miles](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.509) and technically does not need one). He also has a chute presumably for emergencies.

Comment: You might want to add the altitude limits that apply to aircraft and the airspace classes.

Comment: I think there's a pretty good chance that the FAA would classify it as an ultralight, not an experimental aircraft. In that case, part 103 would apply, not part 91. But that's all speculation until/unless someone tries to operate it in the US.

Comment: Why do you say class E airspace? Generally things like drones and ultralights, are banned from class E

Comment: Mostly because you dont need a radio to enter but I was unaware ultralights were banned from E, I will update to reflect.