# What equipment was Jetpack man using? What will happen if he gets caught?

Tags: faa-regulations

[‘The Jetpack Guy Is Back’: Los Angeles Sighting Draws an Inquiry, Again](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/07/30/us/jetpack-sighting-lax.html)

[Video from pilot shows what appears to be jetpack man in Los Angeles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnLW5SHzMNs)

First, looking at the video it seems like this guy is pretty far up there. What sort of jetpack would he be using? Does something exist on the market where this could be done? If not, what would he have had to build on his own?

Second, what kind of ramifications is this person facing should they be caught? Had they interacted with ATC/had the necessary equipment to fly through controlled airspace would he have been allowed to proceed with his flight?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/764/62)

Comment: "*Had they interacted with ATC/had the necessary equipment to fly through controlled airspace would he have been allowed to proceed with his flight?*" You seem to answer your own question. Maybe the question should be about what would be the necessary equipment and procedures to follow.

Comment: Your first link is paywalled.